# Overriden paint() function in JPanel subclass never called?

Tags: java, jpanel, paint, repaint

I'm having a problem overriding the paint() method in my JPanel subclass, ChordEditor.  Even when I override the paint() method, add it to the frame, and call repaint() the paint() method is never called.  The printout "entering paint function" does not print.  Can anyone help me with this?

My ChordEditor class:

```
public class ChordEditor extends JPanel{

    ArrayList<Chord> chordArray = new ArrayList<Chord>();

    public ChordEditor() {
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("entering paint function");
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        System.out.println("drawing line");
        g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 40, 40);
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Where I add it to the JFrame:

```
ChordEditor ce = new ChordEditor();
m_frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
m_frame.add(ce);
m_frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: You should override [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) instead of [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29). Does the line show?

Comment: Don't override `paint(Graphics)` in a `JPanel`, but instead `paintComponent(Graphics)`, but more often, don't extend `JPanel` at all.

Comment: `g.dispose();`  Only dispose of a `Graphics` instance if you create it explicitly.

Comment: I tried changing paint to paintComponent.  No change.  The function wasn't even called.

Comment: Do you ever see `entering paint function` printed, or are you specifically referring to it being missing after your call to `repaint()`?

Comment: @DuncanJones - entering paint function never printed.

Comment: @duncanjones - what do you mean with "it being missing"

Comment: @AncientPyro You answered my question fine, apologies for the confusing wording. "It being missing" was referring to there not being any output on stdout.

Comment: @DuncanJones - All right, but where should I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you issue a [`repaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) immediately after you added the component suggests that you do so on an already visible frame. **Perhaps you should [`validate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) the frame first.** The following works for me:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class ChordEditor extends JPanel {

    public ChordEditor() {
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("entering paint function");
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        System.out.println("drawing line");
        g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 40, 40);
        //g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame m_frame = new JFrame();
        m_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        m_frame.setSize(600, 400);
        m_frame.setVisible(true);
        ChordEditor ce = new ChordEditor();
        m_frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        m_frame.add(ce);
        m_frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        m_frame.validate();
    }
}
```

As already stated in comments to your question, you should override [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) instead of [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29), and you should not call [`dispose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29) as you didn't create this Graphics context.

The calls to [`sync`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync%28%29) and [`repaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) should be unneccessary as well, I guess you added them in an attempt to solve this issue here. So you might remove them once things work for you. You also might consider adding all components to the frame before making it visible. Doing so will cause an implicit validation and is the more common approach to windows with a fixed configuration of controls they contain.

Comment: All right - I tried the validate thing.  It kind of works.  The console prints out "entering paint function" a couple hundred times(literally).  However, the frame freezes and the line is never drawn.  In addition, after a couple hundred printouts of "entering paint function," I get this error:  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @AncientPyro, drop the `sync` and see if that solves the issue. If it doesn't, drop more and more of your code until you identified the cause of this infinite recursion, avoid it and restore all the rest.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooo much!!!!!!!!!!  The problem was the: super.paint(g);  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @AncientPyro: Let me guess, you renamed the method from `paint` to `paintComponent`, and had it call `super.paint(g)` which, among others, calls `paintComponent`… Don't forget to accept an answer eventually.